# How to open all frame in new tab or window

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I set 4 frame in my webpage. there are banner frame, left frame, contain frame & footer frame. Left frame have some link this link show on contain frame. If i click left frame link then this link information show on contain frame. But when I am going to open this link in a new tab or window then link information show whole page in new window. banner frame, left frame, contain frame, footer frame don't show in new tab or window. How can I show all frame in new tab or window if any one open my webpage as a new tab or window.

Comment: Is there any way you can avoid frames?  If I go through life without ever seeing another site built with frames, I'd be good with that.  Also, you've asked 9 questions and accepted zero answers.  Please accept some answers, you'll get more help.

Comment: Frames... Wait... What were those things again?

Answer (score 0):

Use the target property of  the anchor tag

```
<a href="" target="yourframe">Link</a>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html

Comment: But I would definitely agree with Surreal Dreams. Using frames is a bad practice.

Comment: I guess this was the actual question: "How to show all frames in new tab or window, if someone opens my webpage in a new tab or window?" Answer for this is: redirect your pages, if they are opened without `frameset`.

Comment: Yeah, you could redirect to your main page (with all your frames) in a new tab or window, with a target name passed as a parameter in the url and onload redirect your content frame to that page.